# Mountain chain and geometry

Tags: geometry, maps, data

Concerning Mountains chain (in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountain_ranges) where can I find any maps with Montains chain and also geometry for those?

Answer (score 1):

You can find global elevation data [here](http://vterrain.org/Elevation/).

You can find elevation data by country [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata).

You can turn these data into maps by using free software like DIVA-GIS or QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for this on a global scale (e.g.  1:10,000,000), you could try the free and nicely formatted data available from the seasoned cartographers at Natural Earth:  [http://www.naturalearthdata.com/](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/)

Look under "physical region features" for the names of major mountain chains, which can be paired with the "shaded relief map" in raster format.  Again, these work best for maps showing the entire earth, or large portions of it.  They are not detailed enough to show, say, a single small country.